# Applying last_fit function in tidy models

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidy, tidymodels

If I understood correctly, to apply `last_fit` function in tidy package, I need to have a split object that created using `rsample::initial_split()`.

However in a situation that I have separate training data and test data at the very beginning, I don't want to use `initial_split` function to split the data into training and testing.

Since I cannot create a split object, Couldnt I use `last_fit` function?

Comment: You can use `bind_rows` to bind the two datasets an then use `initial_time_split` to take the first proportion of the binded data as training data. Then you can continue as usual with `last_fit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an `rsplit` object from existing testing and training sets, you can use `make_splits()`:

```r
library(rsample)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data(cells, package = "modeldata")

make_splits(
  cells %>% filter(case == "Train"),
  cells %>% filter(case == "Test")
)
#> <Analysis/Assess/Total>
#> <1009/1010/2019>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Alternatively you can *not* use `last_fit()` and manually `fit()` on the training and `predict()` on the testing set.